# I want to change the screen using an if statement for the data received from the realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, refresh

This code gets the red_score and blue_score data from the realtime database and turns the screen when the score reaches 5.
But in the middle refresh(100); Red_win.class intent keeps refreshing because of refresh(100) codes.
I want to refresh only when receiving data. What should I do?

Is there any other way to refresh?
not buttons

```
public class TournamentFinal extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView TeamRedScore,TeamBlueScore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tournament_final);
        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case R.id.setting:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, SettingActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                    case R.id.support:
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, SupportActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                    case R.id.about_us:
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, InfoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                    case R.id.share:
                        Intent intent6 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, ShareActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent6);
                        break;
                    case R.id.game:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, TournamentFinal.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.home:
                        Intent intent8 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent8);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case R.id.setting:
                        Intent intent11 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, SettingActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent11);
                        break;
                    case R.id.game:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, TournamentFinal.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        fetchdata();
        TeamRedScore = findViewById(R.id.team_red_score);
        TeamBlueScore = findViewById(R.id.team_blue_score);
    }
    public void fetchdata(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Team_score");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String red_score = snapshot.child("red_score").getValue().toString();
                    TeamRedScore.setText(red_score);
                    String blue_score = snapshot.child("blue_score").getValue().toString();
                    TeamBlueScore.setText(blue_score);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(red_score) == 5){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, Red_win.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(blue_score) == 5) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TournamentFinal.this, Blue_win.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
        refresh(100);
    }

    private void refresh(int milliseconds){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fetchdata();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, milliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the framework you're using but this seems like the perfect opportunity to use OOP, namely in the form of mutators and accessors (getters and setters). I can't give you a clear cut answer because just looking at this makes me think you're gonna have do some restructuring altogether

Comment: Since you call `addValueEventListener`, Firebase already continues to monitor the data at `reference` and invokes your code in its `onDataChange` method when the data changes. So you shouldn't need `refresh(100);`. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: The screen appears normally, but the data must be continuously received in real time and refreshed.
If refresh(100); is removed, refresh will not work.

Comment: If I don't remove refresh(100);, the next screen will refresh continuously.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why you would have to use `refresh(100)`. Isn't onDataChange() getting called when something in the database changes?